# Finding out whether function is well-defined or not.

Tags: functions, modular-arithmetic

I have this question, I can't seem to figure out.

> Consider the function $f: \mathbb{Z}/5 \mathbb{Z} \to{} \mathbb{R}$
>    defined by the formula $f([n]_5)= \sin(n *\pi)$.  Is this function
>    well-defined?  Be sure to explain your answer fully.

So far I have $$n' = n+5k$$
$$f([n']_5) = \sin(n'\cdot \pi)$$
$$=\sin((n+5k)\cdot \pi)$$

Not sure what to do here. Thanks.

Comment: for all $n$ you've $\sin(n\pi)=0$

Comment: Yes, so does that mean it is well-defined?

Comment: "well-defined" means that the function has the same value, regardless of which representative of an equivalence class you choose.  i.e. for $[2]$, whether you pick $2$ or $7$ or $-3$.

Comment: Alright, so with that... the function is well-defined... right?

Comment: $n+5k = ? \mod 2\pi$. What can be $?$